# I need to identify a diode on a PCB

Tags: diodes, identification

I need help as I'm new to electronics.

I need to identify a diode in a PCB that I'm currently working on. Do you have any idea or advice on how to identify the diode?

The diode which I need to identify is D1 in the picture below.

[image: Photo of PCB]
[image: Photo of PCB bottom]

IC1 is a Vishay TCST1030 Transmissive Optical Sensor with Phototransistor Output - [datasheet here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83763/tcst1030.pdf)

Q1 is an NPN transistor (SOT-23) [datasheet here](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/marking/226251/BILIN/S9013.html)

Below is the circuit diagram that I drew, based on the PCB.

[image: Hand-drawn schematic]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff1n46.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: this looks like very generic diode type, might be hard, if not impossible to figure out... Is there any text on the IC1(…? big black unit.) component? It looks like some kind of photo-sensor? Also, what kind of device is this from?

Comment: the black box thing is a phototransistor (TCST1030 Vishay) and Q1 is a transistor NPN (SOT-23). The only thing that i need to know is the diode. This is from a PCB which controls a motor.

Comment: IF it's a diode a 1N4148 or 1N914 will probably work. It MAY be a zener or have special magic - but probably not.

Comment: Do you have a schematic diagram of the circuit?  Indicate off board connections as well.  There's a schematic editor built in to the site, though it won't work from a phone.

Comment: @JRE nope i dont have the schematic drawing of the board thats why i need a way of identifying it.

Comment: The [TCST1030 - data sheet here](http://www.vishay.com/docs/83763/tcst1030.pdf) is not, of course a photo transistor. It's a transistor PLUS a diode - saying that and giving a datasheet link will help people to help you.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon yeah i think its a normal diode but there is a possibility that it could be another type of diode such as zener diode.

Comment: Sure "ALL you want to know is xxx" BUT typing people's hands and blindfolding them is usually not helpful to getting help. You could very easily trace out the cct and use the built in cct editor to add a cct so it will be much easier to wot what's up.

Comment: You could sketch out what you've discovered.  It looks like a simple two sided board so it shouldn't be too difficult to trace.  From the diagram you have a better chance of seeing what the diode does, and from that a better chance of figuring out what type it is.

Comment: You SAY that Q1 is an npn transistor. How do you know that ? If it is and if it shares pinout with 99.99876% of its brethren then collector goes to the bottom track. emitter probably goes to R2 and thence to D1 and thence to IC1. Its possible - but how do you know. Any chance of a cct diagram?

Comment: Because there is a marking on top of Q1 which leads me to the name of the component.

Comment: There is a marking '''J3'' on top of Q1 that leads me to conclude that its a NPN transistor

Comment: @alexhelloworld are you sure that Q1 is a transistor? Googlin `J3` shows me that it's a `ZC831` varactor diode

Comment: @Swedgin Why would you use a varactor diode in this particular circuit? It's definitely a transistor IMO. I would imagine the diode would be a snubber diode to be across the motor then.

Comment: The junction where R2 and R3 should probably be connected to ground, and the other end of the motor should likely go to the power supply.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat I don't know, but if you look up `J3` in any SMD codebook it will point to `ZC831`;;

`pJ3` points to an n-channel mosfet `BSH103`

Comment: [This one](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/j3) does show several NPN transistors too. Sure there are some varactors and LDOs too, but those just don't fit in for me, while a NPN with a typical pinout does seem to fit quite well.

Comment: @RichardtheSpacecat Yes, you're right. Thanks for the new link. Didn't know of that one.

Comment: Your circuit diagram isn't making sense to me. Can you show us a photo of the other side of the board? A photo of the device (including motor) might also be helpful.

Comment: Diode is revere polarity connected across the motor. A diode or a zener would work. Diode would be more usual. Why did it blow. | Presumably motor is not magic powered and showing other end (presumably grounded) would be usual.  There is an in system schematic editor that makes drawing readable diagrams easy.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon i guess maybe its the diode that causes the blow so thats why i need to make sure it was really the diode.

Comment: @alexhelloworld How about actually telling us what your poblem is rather than offering peeks at issues out of context. You NOW say "causing the blow". Knowing what that means (we can GUESS) and in total context may help us help you. || Best guess: The diode is a backl emf protection/ free wheel diode on the motor. The diode failed because Murpht / overvoltage/stuff happens and the motor noise spikes then caused xxx.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The motor didnt work so i want to see what is the causes of this malfunction , so i went to look at the PCB to learn how the circuit works and eventually test every components on the PCB in hope for finding the error . In order to do this, i have to identify all of the components and their functions in the PCB. As i already identified all other components except the diode , i was suspecting that the diode is cause of the problem , so i want to buy another diode if and only if i knew the part number of the diode.